# dispatch is not a function how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error when I click a button calling the `addserver` function

```
onAddClick() {
  const { dispatch } = this.props;
  dispatch(ServersActions.startEditing());
}
```

and my `startEditing` function :

```
export function startEditing(id) {   return (dispatch, getState) => {
 if (!id) {
   dispatch({ type: START_EDITING_SERVER });
   return;
 }

 const { config } = getState();
 const cryptoSecret = config.data.crypto.secret;

 const server = config.data.servers.find(srv => srv.id === id);
 if (!server) {
   return;
 }

 const decryptedServer = sqlectron.servers.decryptSecrects(server, cryptoSecret);

 dispatch({ type: START_EDITING_SERVER, server: decryptedServer });   };

}
```

Could you tell my why I get this error and how I fix it?

Comment: I would think that `dispatch` inside of the `startEditing` function is not referencing `this.props.dispatch`.

Comment: how to fix this ??

Comment: post the entire file with `onAddClick ` function

Comment: does the error point to onAddClick or startEditing

Comment: the error point in  onAddClick  and i define dispatch as proptype required function

Comment: Did you `connect()` your component?

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> the error point in onAddClick and i define dispatch as proptype required function

If PropTypes don't throw error my guess is that you didn't bind your function

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  ...
  this.onAddClick = this.onAddClick.bind(this);
}
```

nor used instance properties defined with arrow functions:

```
onAddClick = () => {
  const { dispatch } = this.props;
  dispatch(ServersActions.startEditing());
}
```

so `this.props` is referencing to some other component props.